# My app on raspberry pi won't give any output on screen

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

Actually, this is my first question on StackOverflow community...

Recently I set up a raspberry pi with windows 10 IOT core and it worked fine.
I proceed by installing the project in this link:

https://blog.falafel.com/windows-iot-core-sensing-sound/

the code in the link above worked fine without any errors and successfully deployed to the raspberry pi

the problem is that it does not give any video output when I plug HDMI cable all I get was a logo on screen in the shape of a square with a cross inside

[Screen Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrJ3T.jpg)

I've tried to download and run samples from Microsoft website (like hello world sample) and it worked fine with video output has been coded.

please give me any tips, fixes or comments that will help me pass this issue.

I'll be so glad to hear from you.

best regards

Comment: Which version is the Windows IoT Core?Have you changed the Target version of the project to the version on your device?I have tested on Windows IoT Core 16299.309 with HDMI cable connected to my display.It works.

Comment: The visual studio only support the target version 10.0.16299 in general, but my IoT core version is 16299.248 .. I'll try to update my IoT core image and I will see what will happen

Comment: If there is some progress, please feel free and let me know.

Comment: Nothing changed .. I updated my IoT core version and the problem continued happening

Comment: Have you debugged the when running the application?

Comment: yes of-course I've debugged my app before installing it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you may be having is that you have got an endless loop running in your code and it is preventing the UI from rendering. I had the same problem and I discovered that it was because I had a while(true) loop and I had to put the code in a separate thread.Hope it helps